# Startup assembly Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StartupBootstrapper failed to execute. See the inner exception for more details

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I setup AppService .net core 2.1 and integrate AppInsight on my product. Got exception on log:

[image]

On github have ticket related: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14547, when we restart app service this issue occur. I tried to make sample code, but can't reproduce.